# Problems with facade in javascript and Mongo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am writting a little app to calculate and keep track of how much gas my car is using. But i have a problem with my facade.

When i am trying to add some new details to my database, i only get a empty object somehow. 
I know the problem is in my facade, and maybe some of you can see what it is.

(Don't worry about the name of the method)

```
function addTitle (kilometer, liter, kmLiter, callback){
var data = {
    kilometer: kilometer,
    liter: liter,
    kmLiter: kmLiter
}
detail.create({details:data}, function(err, result){
    if(err)
        return callback(err);
    else
        callback(null, result);
});
};
```

And this is the model of the DB

```
var DetailSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  details:[{
  kilometer: String,
  liter: String,
  kmLiter: String}
  ]
});
```

mongoose.model('Details', DetailSchema, "details");

Anybody that can find the error?

Comment: Well i got your point! But can you suggest what i can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your schema definition of `details` being an array is what you want, you need to also make `details` an array when you create new docs.

So your function should change to:

```
function addTitle (kilometer, liter, kmLiter, callback){
    var data = {
        kilometer: kilometer,
        liter: liter,
        kmLiter: kmLiter
    }
    detail.create({details: [data]}, callback);
}
```